# HTML form input not being recognized by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I have the super awesome jQuery [validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and [form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugins working all over my site without problems. Unfortunately, for one of my forms I have this weird problem where no form data gets submitted regardless of what I type into the form's textboxes.

To show you what I mean, when I `console.log` the field data before typing ("stored data") and upon submission ("live data") this is what I get ([serialized using $.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)):

```
stored data: full_name=&email_address=&password=  
live data: full_name=&email_address=&password=
```

So nothing is being submitted on this form, whereas the "live data" for all other forms on my site which use the exact same JS codebase display whatever is inputed.

**UPDATE** Here's a [JSFiddle for this form](http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/xqk7V/12/).

**UPDATE 2** I'm realizing that this form's elements aren't being recognized by Javascript. So the background doesn't turn red if I do this.

```
$('#email_address').focus(
function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color' : 'red'});
});
```

Wow this is totally confusing, thoughts?

Comment: @AkhilSekharan yes but so do all my other forms, what does this suggest to you?

Comment: Is it possible to show the relevant part of html and js?

Comment: Firebug console shows no errors? Have you tried logging the object you are passing to $.param? How is that object being retrieved from the form? Could you create a jsbin/fiddle with the bare minimum code that recreates the issue? Personally I have found doing so helps me isolate and find the code that is slightly different from the rest.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates this, can use cdn resources for plugins and set `debug:true` in validate options

Comment: @AmithGeorge, and -@Akhil, I'm working on making a JSFiddle right now to isolate the problem, will add it to my question when I'm done...thanks for your help....

Comment: @AmithGeorge et al., here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/xqk7V/12/

Comment: if you submit the form, does your url change? usually if I have an error in my validation, all of the submitted values end up on the url as query parameters. Is that happening in your case as well?

Comment: @E.J.Brennan thanks for your thoughts, no the url doesn't change, there is no error in the validation which doesn't make sense either b/c one of the fields should only accept valid email addresses, ugh, this is frustrating,

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$(document.body).on('click', ".ajaxFormBtn"
```

and

```
<button data-loading-text="Saving..." class=" btn btn-green btn-large txt24" 
            value="Sign up" id="signupModalBtn" ><i class="icon-key icon-signin"></i> 
            Sign up</button>
```

Notice anything missing from the button's class attribute?

Comment: thanks for noticing, sorry that was a copy paste error, i'll correct the fiddle but this isn't the problem...

Comment: with that class there it reads what i enter
stored data: full_name=&email_address=&password=
live data: full_name=234234234&email_address=werwer&password=r

Comment: yes, this jsfiddle isn't recreating the problem, i knew that be the case but didn't know else to say it to everyone, that's was i trying to brainstorm on scenarios in which the field values could be erased